# R time-series prediction with linear model

Tags: r

I have an XTS dataframe where I am trying to fit a linear model to a set of future dates. I have divided the dataframe into a past and present (for other reasons) and I fit the linear model as follows

```
lin_mod <- lm(PastExchg ~ Time, data = BackDF)
```

That's fine. But when I try to make predictions using `predict` on the `Time` column for the future data, I get an error

```
ForwDF$pred <- predict(lin_mod, newdata= ForwDF$Time)
```

I suspect this may have something to do with the fact that the `Time` column is in Date format. Or perhaps that the `Time` column is irregular. How can I fix this?

ForwDF looks like

```
              PLN       Time
2004-06-28 4.5331 2004-06-28
2004-06-29 4.5270 2004-06-29
2004-06-30 4.5025 2004-06-30
2004-07-01 4.5155 2004-07-01
2004-07-02 4.5258 2004-07-02
2004-07-05 4.5304 2004-07-05
2004-07-06 4.5138 2004-07-06
2004-07-07 4.5330 2004-07-07
```

`PLN` is the true value of the column (which I will compare the predictions in `pred` against later--once I can get them!!).

Comment: Predict is expecting a data frame, and you gave it a vector. When you pass the data frame, predict will find the correct variable according to how `lin_mod` was specified. That is why the answer from Elias should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ForwDF$pred <- predict(lin_mod, newdata= data.frame(Time = ForwDF$Time))
```

Let me know if it worked.

Edit: See the comment of Jason, for the explenation why your solution did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
# Create similar data
Time <- sort(sample(seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date() - 200, length.out = 200))[1:100])
df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100), Time = Time)

# Linear regression and prediction
lin_mod <- lm(y ~ Time, data = df)
df$pred <- predict(lin_mod, newdata=list(Time = df$Time)
```